# What happens when a task is deleted in RTOS?

Tags: rtos

I want to know **what happens exactly when a task is deleted in RTOS ?** 
Does this means that

The RTOS will not schedule the task any more ?

or

The task code is removed from the system memories ?

Comment: There isn't one single rule as different RTOSs follow different standards.

Answer (score 1):

A deleted task won't be considered by the scheduler again.  If RAM was dynamically allocated when the task was created then that RAM should get deallocated.  No code associated with the task will be deleted from ROM.  "Exactly" what happens is specific to each particular RTOS.